# Facebook JavaScript SDK Logout does not invalidate access tokens

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the code below to logout a user from my application:

```
 function logOut(){
    FB.logout(function(response){ 
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Checking at the console log the response shows that the user is logged out

[image]

But when I debug the token, the console shows that it's still valid:

[image]

This is weird because as per Facebook documentation:

> Calling FB.logout will also invalidate the access token that you have
>   for the user, unless you have extended the access token.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Where are you getting the token from, and when?

Comment: @CBroe I get the token from the response I got from FB.logout.